# I want to sort td elements within different trs. When Mobile Size Becomes

Tags: html-table, responsive-design

```
<table id="layouttable">
    <tr>
        <td class='col1'>1</td>
        <td class='col2'>2</td>
        <td class='col3'>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='col4'>4</td>
        <td class='col5'>5</td>
        <td class='col6'>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When Mobile Size Becomes

1  4 
2 
5 
3 
6

I want to list them in the order above.

flex - order was not available because of tr.

Does anyone know of a really simple solution like this?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to change to css(@media).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and very dirty solution:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop-table
  {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .mobile-table
  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
    <table id="layouttable" class="desktop-table">
        <tr>
            <td class='col1'>1</td>
            <td class='col2'>2</td>
            <td class='col3'>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='col4'>4</td>
            <td class='col5'>5</td>
            <td class='col6'>6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="layouttable-mobile" class="mobile-table">
             <tr><td class='col1'>1</td></tr>
             <tr><td class='col4'>4</td></tr>
             <tr><td class='col2'>2</td></tr>

             <tr><td class='col5'>5</td></tr>
             <tr><td class='col3'>3</td></tr>
             <tr><td class='col6'>6</td></tr>
    </table>
```